# How to add elements to a sub list in Python?

Tags: python, list, insert

Consider a list inside a list

```
list1 = ["element1","element2",["subelement1","subelement2"]]
```

subelement1 can be accessed by index [2][0]

```
print (list1[2][0])
```

But how can I insert elements at [2][x] position if only two parameters can be passed to insert function.

```
list.insert(index, element)
```

Lets say i want to insert `"subelement0"` at `[2],[0]`. That makes the list :

```
list1 = ["element1","element2",["subelement0","subelement1","subelement2"]]
```

Comment: you mean `["element1", "subelement1", "element2", "subelement2"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to insert element to sublist as below:

```
list1[2].insert(0, 'subelement0') 
print(list1)
#  ['element1', 'element2', ['subelement0', 'subelement1', 'subelement2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to extend the answer posted by @Andersson. It would be nice to checking the type of the list element, then `insert` a new value.

```
def list_modify(element_to_add):
  list1 = ["element1", "element2", ["subelement1", "subelement2"]]
  for index, value in enumerate(list1):
      if isinstance(value, list):
          list1[index].insert(0, element_to_add)
  print(list1)
  #  ['element1', 'element2', ['subelement0', 'subelement1', 'subelement2']]
if __name__ == "__main__":
  list_modify('subelement0')
```